# c# MVC 5 IValidatableObject personalización de mensajes de error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con c# MVC 5 y estoy personalizando errores en las clases del modelo con IValidatableObject utilizandolo de la forma convencional:

```
errores.Add(new ValidationResult("error en la captura de datos",new string[] { "propiedad-del_modelo_1", "propiedad-del_modelo_2" })
```

Y de acuerdo con en esto, los mensajes se muestran en la vista en los lugares:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.propiedad-del_modelo_1, "", new { @class = "red-text text-darken-3" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.propiedad-del_modelo_2, "", new { @class = "red-text text-darken-3" })
```

He diseñado una validación para un conjunto de propiedades del modelo y no quisiera que se mostrara junto con un @Html.ValidationMessageFor en la vista sino en un  o un  o algo que me permita mostrar el mensaje de error en cualquier sitio de la página.
¿Es esto posible?

Comment: ¿Agregar el error en el layout?

Comment: Si santiago, mostrar el error en el layout en un div o en un  span sin que esté limitado a un @Html.ValidationMessageFor. Es eso posible ?

Comment: Pues puedes utilizar ajax para agregar los errores en el layout

Comment: ¿Haz usado mvc con ajax?

Comment: Claro Santiago, lo uso muy seguido, sin embargo, en este proyecto le doy más relevancia a la comprobación de errores en el servidor. Uso data annotations normalmente, pero IValidatableObject me permite ampliar mucho más las posibilidades de validación. En este proyecto, hago una comprobación por "conjuntos" de propiedades de la clase del módelo y al encontrar un error este no sería de una propiedad en concreto sino del conjunto por lo tanto, me gustaría que en el layout este error no se mostrara debajo de un control sino del titulo del conjunto de controles, por ejemplo en un div o en un span.

Comment: Y llamas al método con ajax o por defecto como lo pone razor